# What's the kernel of $w\mapsto w \bullet \bullet$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

for $v\in K^n$, the dot product defines a linear transformation
$-\bullet v: K^n\to K, w\mapsto w\bullet v$. Let $e_i$ be the i-the basis vector of $K^n$. What's the kernel of $-\bullet e_i$?

I know that the dot product of two vectors is zero if they are orthogonal. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:=-\bullet e_i$. If $x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in K^n$, then

$$x \in ker(f) \iff f(x)=0 \iff x \bullet e_i=0 \iff x_i=0.$$

Comment: Ooops, yes, thanks